# Unable to store ascii value in a variable

Tags: shell, quoting, ksh, printf

I am trying to convert hex to decimal to ascii and store it in a variable.
I am using the following code.

```
HEX=30
DEC=`printf "%d\n" 0x${HEX}`
echo "$DEC"
ASC=`printf \\$(printf '%03o' $DEC)`
echo "$ASC"
```

I am getting the following error  syntax error :

```
`(' unexpected
```

I am using Solaris 10, and `ksh`. I do not want to use a function for ascii and call it to store the value. I want to be able to do it without using a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Jeff Schaller for correcting my syntax error.
I found a solution to my problem, this is working in Solaris 10.

`script:`

```
#!/bin/ksh
HEX=30
DEC=`printf "%d\n" 0x${HEX}`  ##Converted Hex to decimal
echo "$DEC"
OCT=$(printf '%o' $DEC)   ##Converted decimal to octal
echo "$OCT"
ASCI=$(printf \\$OCT)  ##Finally converted OCTAL to ASCII.
echo "$ASCI"
```

`output:`

```
48
60
0
```

Apparently, we have to convert decimal to octal before printing out to ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistakenly escaping the `$` twice, leading `printf` to see `printf \$( ...` instead of (what I assume you want) of substituting the inside printf results. To that end, you could simplify that whole statement to: `ASC=$(printf '%03o' $DEC)`

Comment: its not giving the right value. For a Hex number of 34, The ASCII value must be 0. Intead its giving out 060. Something's not correct.

Comment: Your script is taking a hex value, converting it to decimal (%d), then converting it again to octal (%o).

Comment: Yeah. i was told that we have to convert to octal to get ascii value in shell script. Do you know any other way of getting ascii value of hexa?

Comment: @ayrton_senna what do you mean by "ascii value"? A character?

Comment: I am confused. ASCII is a character encoding. Hex and octal are different bases for numbers. The only common ground here is (possibly) an alternate base representation of an ASCII character.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The ASCII equivalents of decimal can been seen from this chart http://www.asciichart.com/ and the solution I posted seems to be working fine in ksh. i don not personally know how and why this conversion to octal is required to print ascii charater.